# Recursive relationship in JPA lost under postgresql but preserved under h2 database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, h2

I have a recursive relationship that is parent-child like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person implements Persistable<UUID>, Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
    @JsonView(View.Person.class)
    private UUID id;
    
    @Column(name = "parent_id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
    @JsonView(View.Person.class)
    private UUID parentId;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) // this is additionally added as the getter is overriden to return a subset of the children - shouldn't be causing the issue
    private Set<Person> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have an add child method that adds a new child to an existing (parent) person :

```
@Transactional
public Person addChild(UUID parentPersonId) {
    Person childPerson = new Person(); // creating the child and adding properties to it, not important in this case
    childPerson.setParentId(parentPersonId);
    return personRepository.save(childPerson);
}
```

I also have an update method that updates Person :

```
@Transactional
public Person updatePerson(Person person) {
    Person savedPerson = personRepository.findById(person.getId()).get();
    // more updates here, but skipped as not relevant to the issue
    savedPerson.setChildren(new HashSet<>());
    return personRepository.save(savedPerson);
}
```

If using postgresql (database for the production environment) and following these steps :

1. Create parent person.
2. Create child person of the parent person - using the *addChild* method : **parent_id** is set in the database record of the child person.
3. Execute the *updatePerson* method for the parent person - automatically the child person loses its relation to the parent, under the hood the query is executed :

**UPDATE person SET parent_id=NULL WHERE id=@child_person_id;**

However if following the same steps under H2 database (running an integration test using H2 database), the additional query to update the child person and lose the connection between child and parent is never executed.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how can I best mimic the postgresql behavior in my integration test that is using the H2 database ?